# A marginal space splitting $\{ \psi \}^{\perp}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, integration

Let $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb C)$. Is there a continuous projection from $\{ \psi \}^{\perp}$ onto 
$$
\left\{ \varphi \in L^2(\mathbb R^2) \:\:\Big| \int \overline{\psi}(x,y) \varphi(x,y)\text{d}y = 0 \text{ a.e. in } x \in \mathbb R  \right\}\:\:
?$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The set you describe, call it $E$, is a closed linear subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and therefore we have an orthogonal projection from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ onto $E$. Explicitly, given $\phi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, define $g(x) = \int \overline{\psi}(x,y)\phi(x,y)\, dy$ and $h(x) = \int |\psi(x,y)|^2\, dy$. Then the map $\phi(x,y) \mapsto \phi(x,y) - \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\psi(x,y)$ is the orthogonal projection onto $E$. (The fact that $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\psi(x,y)$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a little exercise in Fubini-Tonelli.)

Comment: Thanks ! And would you know whether the operator $\varphi \mapsto \int \overline{\psi}(x,y)\varphi(x,y) \text{d} y$, from $\{ \psi \}^{\perp}$ to $L^2$, is surjective (or "almost surjective"), please ? ($\psi$ and its marginals are a.e non-vanishing)